# asp.net apply jquery autocomplete to same boxes with same suffix

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I have a jquery autocomplete in my asp.net webform which I would like to use on various textboxes within the page.

I have managed to make it work if I put the full ID of the textbox but, obviously, it only works on that textbox.

All textboxes end on _CUR so I assume there is something missing, but I am not sure how to go about it...
Any help is appreciated.

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {                   

        var availableTags = ["EUR","USD",  "ARG","CAD","AUD","TRW","CHI" ];
        $("#_CUR").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
         });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The # selector in jQuery is an exact ID match selector. You are looking for an ends with. There isn't one specifically for ID, but you can use the general attribute ends with selector to achieve the same goal.

Try this:

```
 var availableTags = ["EUR","USD",  "ARG","CAD","AUD","TRW","CHI" ];
    $("[id$='_CUR']").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
     });
```

Documentation available here:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/#attributevalue

Comment: this is what I was looking for. I did check the autocomplete API documentation but didn't see the attributevalue section, which was somewhere else so it seems.

Comment: Ya all the selectors are independent of the actions you do to the selected elements. Think of it as "What elements do I want to modify" coupled with the modifications you want to make. Selectors are universal to jQuery.